# CSS: How to use psuedo-class to color span element

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using [React Big Calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-big-calendar) and I want to color the date with a different color. Is it possible to do so.
I have tried with many example and stylings but not able to achieve my goal.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciate for such case.
Thanks in advance

*Code*

```
<div class="date-item">
    <a href="#">
        <span role="itemheader" aria-sort="none">Mon 01</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="date-item">
    <a href="#">
        <span role="itemheader" aria-sort="none">Tue 02</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="date-item">
    <a href="#">
        <span role="itemheader" aria-sort="none">Wed 03</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

For example: Here I want to color **Mon 01** with *Mon* with **black color** and *01* with **grey color** for every date element.

Comment: Is code that you provided generated by `React Big Calendar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a look at [`background-clip:text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) and a linear-gradient to show through the letters.

> /* Keyword values */
>
> background-clip: border-box;
>
> background-clip: padding-box;
>
> background-clip: content-box;
>
> **background-clip: text;**

You ca make your gradient start from right to cover your 2 digits that has to be grey.

example

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

span {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, grey 1.25em, black 1.25em);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}


/* extra demo */
.even {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start;
}

.even a,
.even span {
  display: block;
}

.even span {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, green 1.25em, red 1.25em);
}
```

```html
<div class="date-item">
  <a href="#">
    <span role="itemheader" aria-sort="none">Mon 01</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="date-item">
  <a href="#">
    <span role="itemheader" aria-sort="none">Tue 02</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="date-item">
  <a href="#">
    <span role="itemheader" aria-sort="none">Wed 03</span>
  </a>
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <span>Thursday 05</span><br>
      <span>Fr 06</span>

    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<!-- extra demo -->
<div class="even">
  <div class="date-item">
    <a href="#">
      <span role="itemheader" aria-sort="none">Mon 01</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="date-item">
    <a href="#">
      <span role="itemheader" aria-sort="none">Tue 02</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="date-item">
    <a href="#">
      <span role="itemheader" aria-sort="none">Wed 03</span>
    </a>
    <div>
      <a href="#">
        <span>Thursday 05</span>
        <span>Fr 06</span>

      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate your help. It helps me to learn this new thing. Thank you once again.